# Invalid type-check typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a weird *type-check* ignore of *mismatching* types (`Student` and `Employee`):

```
import { argv } from "process"

class Student {

  // OPTION 1: interchangeable
  // public name: string;
  // constructor(name_: string) { this.name = name_; }

  // OPTION 2: interchangeable
  constructor(public readonly name: string){}

  // OPTION 3: compile-time error
  // constructor(private readonly name: string){}
  // public getName() { return this.name; }
}

class Employee {

  // OPTION 1: interchangeable
  // public name: string;
  // constructor(name_: string) { this.name = name_; }

  // OPTION 2: interchangeable
  constructor(public readonly name: string){}

  // OPTION 3: compile-time error
  // constructor(private readonly name: string){}
  // public getName() { return this.name; }
}

function printMe(student: Student) {
  console.log(student.name);
}

printMe(new Employee(process.argv[2])); // should issue a compile-time type error (?!)
```

When I try options 1 and 2 I *don't* get a compile-time error:

```
$ npx tsc --strict ./main.ts
```

Only option 3 yields the compile-time error (even *without* `--strict`):

```
$ npx tsc ./main.ts 
main.ts:35:9 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Employee' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Student'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'name'.

35 printMe(new Employee(process.argv[2]));
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: This section of the docs may be relevant  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#relationships-between-classes

Comment: @IainShelvington any idea why the third option *does* get a compile-time type-error?